How to reload GPO Windows firewall after modification by Poweshell using e.g. New-NetFirewallRule or Set-NetFirewallRule
If you make any modification to the GPO Windows firewall rules with the Powershell module NetSecurity using e.g. command New-NetFirewallRule or Set-NetFirewallRule the changes are not applied immediately. I have only been able to do that by making any changing in the MMC GUI afterward (which seems to reload it) or restarting the computer.
It might be possible using Windows Firewall API FwPolicy2 or legacy cmdline tool netsh but I would prefer to do it with the NetSecurity module if possible?

I assume you have tried to reboot or log out and then log back into the user?

Yes, it works after reboot

One way to reload the GPO firewall rules is (of course) to do a simple GPO update:
From the Windows console:
gpupdate /Target:Computer

Powershell:
Invoke-GPUpdate -Target "Computer"

Been looking through the win32 [Windows Firewall with Advanced Security][1] API and I couldn't fine any information on how to target the GPO firewall, so I guess it can only be used for the standard Windows firewall.
But if you do make any changes to the GPO firewall from the MMC console, the changes apply immediately. I wonder if there is a Win32 call to do this or if the MMC console really to a gpupdate behind the scene, it would surprise me.
The powershell command Invoke-GPUpdate is located in the module GroupPolicy which are included in the Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT).
But an error running this saying The security ID structure is invalid. on my test-PC, but it's not domain-joined, maybe that's the reason.
